# How to properly compare decimal characters in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I am having trouble with my code because even if `(Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum) = i`, (e.g. 1.8=1.8), the Boolean still returns `False`. Also the code ends at this point--meaning the program detected `i` to be greater than `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum` at 1.8=1.8. The reason for the BigNum--which is set to 100,000 in my case, is because the scrollbar of a userform is having issues storing decimal numbers so I convert it to an integer to prevent this problem.

In case it might be of any help, `i` is declared as a `Double` type

```
i = Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum
j=0
Do While i <= Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Simulation-Chart").Cells(2 + j, 1) = i
        i = i + ((Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max - Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min) / BigNum) / 10
        j= j + 1
Loop
```

Assuming `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum` = 1.3 and `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum` = 1.8, What I need to code to do is to know that `i` is indeed equal to `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum` then it should print the value of `i` in my spreadsheet as shown as below to be used as my chart's values.

[image]

Other code in the initialization of the userform:

```
Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min = frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupLow.Value * BigNum
Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max = frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupHigh.Value * BigNum
Me.scrFoilMarkup.SmallChange = ((frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupHigh.Value - frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupLow.Value) / 40) * BigNum
Me.scrFoilMarkup.LargeChange = ((frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupHigh.Value - frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupLow.Value) / 8) * BigNum
```

[image]

Initial Parameters form:

[image]

Comment: What is `Me.scrFoilMarkup` ?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin Added initializations on the post

Comment: and what means `j` in your code?

Comment: Sorry that is just to move to the next row for every loop iteration. Just adding bits of my code trying to keep the problem simple. Thought the first form was sufficient as it revolves around the `i` variable not being equal to the while condition

Comment: So, what you want to get? Open Form, then scroll scrollbar and get chart inside form?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin I have another form that sets the parameters of the scrollbars. Then it is translated to the values of `Me.scrFoilMarkup` added an image of it in the main post to give an idea. This is why I need a robust way to convert the decimals

Comment: A really difficult to understand without the file, as your `frmSettings.tbxFoilMarkupHigh.Value` always should equal to `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum`

Comment: Yes that is correct it should be always equal to it. Sadly I cannot send the file due to confidential calculations but I believe everything is correct until the loop portion of the code. Maybe i'll just find a workaround. Thank you for your time. It is hard to really give a full context as it gets complicated fast

Comment: so just give some the values instead of variables and expected results for each.

Comment: Just check the first form of the post and any values plotted as a `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max` and `Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max` should hold true once something goes wrong there is something wrong with the data type/decimal rounding off. It's arbitrary as long as the max portion is greater than the min one

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the variable and formula as the same data types and format

```
Dim i As Variant, BigNum As Long

BigNum = 100000

i = Format(Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum, "#.0")

Do While i <= Format(Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum, "#.0")
    i = Format(i + ((Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max - Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min) / BigNum) / 10, "#.0")
Loop
```

**Edit**
To circumvent OP's decimal problem

```
Dim i As Variant, Mx As Variant, Mn As Variant
Dim BigNum As Long

BigNum = 100000

Mn = Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min
Mx = Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max

i = Mn / BigNum

Do While i <= Mn / BigNum
    i = i + ((Mx - Mn) / BigNum) / 10
Loop
```

Comment: This has caused problems for my code though. The `i`'s are supposed to be in a 0.05 intervals when the minimum is at 1.3 and the maximum is 1.8. What happens is it became in intervals of 0.1 probably due to the rounding off of the format. If there will be a several digit decimal I don't know what problems it may cause down the line. https://ibb.co/LpqC3Rb

Comment: Hold on let me check this out

Comment: Just to clarify `Do While i <= Mn / BigNum` should be `Do While i <= Mx / BigNum` in this context but it still doesn't work it still treats `i` as greater than `Do While i <= Mx / BigNum` I guess it's safe to say it's not a data type issue. Perhaps it's really a very minor rounding off issue i'll just have to come up of a way to limit the number of decimal places I guess and use `Round` or the `Format` as mentioned here as well

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CDbl()`

```
MyDouble = CDbl(Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum) ' Convert result to a Double.
```

Or use `Round`

```
MyDouble = Round((Me.scrFoilMarkup.Min / BigNum),2)
```

test

```
Sub Test()
    sMax = 180000
    sMin = 130000
    BigNum = 100000
    i = sMin / BigNum
    j = 0
    sVar = sMax / BigNum
        Do While Round(i, 2) <= Round(sVar, 2)
            Debug.Print i
                i = i + ((sMax - sMin) / BigNum) / 10
                j = j + 1
        Loop
End Sub
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I tried using this on `Do While i <= CDbl(Me.scrFoilMarkup.Max / BigNum)`, but still thinks `i` is greater than this value at 1.8=1.8

Comment: If the decimal is a several digit decimal won't it cause problems for the code as it'll compare the rounded value?

Comment: So then please attach your file, or explain what you trying to achieve

Comment: Added more details in the post

Comment: Yes I had round prior to making this post actually I removed it because for some reason my code glitched up and ran infinitely. I think I know why now. I only placed round here (in my code equivalent): `i = Round( i + ((sMax - sMin) / BigNum) / 10,2)` and only initially set a decimal place of `1`. Perhaps it should be on both: `Do While Round(i, 2) <= Round(sVar, 2)`. But a decimal place of `2` is also questionable, I guess the only way is to find a way to limit the possible decimals so it won't glitch at some point